# Group by with Sum and joined values Linq to Object

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-objects

I have this list of Debit object

```
List<Debit> debits = new List<Debit>()
{
  new Debit { Code = "A001", Length = 100, Qte = 3, Position = "MCD" },
  new Debit { Code = "A001", Length = 100, Qte = 2, Position = "MED" },
  new Debit { Code = "A001", Length = 200, Qte = 1, Position = "MCG" },
  new Debit { Code = "A002", Length = 200, Qte = 1, Position = "MCD" },
  new Debit { Code = "A003", Length = 200, Qte = 1, Position = "TBD" }
};
```

and I try to group  Debit by Code and Length, sum the `Qte` property of grouped lines and join the Position string separated by a comma ", " in a new list of `Debit` named `sortedDebit`.

```
sortedDebit :  
Code = "A001", Length = 100, Qte = 5, Position = "MCD, MED"  
Code = "A001", Length = 200, Qte = 1, Position = "MCG"  
Code = "A002", Length = 200, Qte = 1, Position = "MCD"  
Code = "A003", Length = 200, Qte = 1, Position = "TBD"
```

Is there a way using `linq` to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is. You can group by the combination of the two fields into a new composite key, which is a simple anonymous object. This requires that each of the fields making up the new composite key is equatable either by object reference or because it has a valid `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementation.

```
var grouped = debits
    .GroupBy(d => new { Code = d.Code, Length = d.Length })
    .Select(g => new Debit() {
        Code = g.Key.Code,
        Length = g.Key.Length,
        Qte = g.Sum(x => x.Qte),
        Position = string.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.Position).Distinct())
    });
```

Comment: I think .GroupBy uses `GetHashCode` behind the scenes. In some cases you have to override that. In some situations I'll generate a  composite string as a comparator, so the 2nd line would become `.GroupBy(d => String.Format("{0}:{1}", d.Code, d.Length))`.

Comment: @CraigJohnson yes, the new composite key must be equatable somehow. Generally this works for e.g. reference types, as the references will be equal. A value type will need a valid `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementation. Concatenating is not an option here, because we still need to access the `Code` and `Length` fields.

Comment: @Alex thank you for this solution, it works perfectly. But above all, thank you for the explanation provided which helps me to deepen my knowledge of Linq.